# Issues running an automatic and unattended clonezilla restore drive

Tags: restore, clonezilla, syslinux

When I try to run an automated and unattended restore via Clonezilla it returns the following error:

```
Now run "ocs_prerun": mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt...
Mount: /mnt: special device /dev/sdb2 does not exist.
Failed to run: mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
Press "Enter" to continue......
```

Then, after hitting Enter it shows the following error:

```
The directory for this inputted image name does NOT exist: /home/partimag/Amentum_04_21_2022
Program Terminated!!!!
"ocs-sr -kl -e1 auto -e2 -batch -r -j2 -scr -p reboot restoredisk Amentum_04_21_2022 sda" finished with error!
```

Here is my syslinux.cfg entry for prerun:

```
label Amentum_04_21_2022
  MENU DEFAULT
  # MENU HIDE
  MENU LABEL Amentum_04_21_2022
  # MENU PASSWD
  kernel /live/vmlinuz
  append initrd=/live/initrd.img boot=live union=overlay username=user config components quiet noswap edd=on nomodeset noeject locales=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard-layouts=NONE ocs_prerun="mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt" ocs_prerun1="mount --bind /mnt /home/partimag" ocs_live_run="ocs-sr -k1 -e1 auto -e2 -batch -r -j2 -scr -p reboot restoredisk Amentum_04_21_2022 sda" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_batch="no" vga=791 ip= net.ifnames=0  splash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1
  TEXT HELP
  VGA mode 1024x768. OK for most of VGA cards.
  ENDTEXT
```

I'm not sure why this is happening because I've prepared these drives this way every other time and I feel like I'm missing something.

This is how they show up when viewing them in the file explorer in Windows. It's just two partitions on the same USB drive:

[image]

CZ(D:) would be sdb1 and images(E:) would be sdb2, right? This is what I've put in both the grub.cfg and the syslinux.cfg file and it's telling me sdb2 does not exist. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!